# Newbie to Interface and oop concepts

Tags: vb.net, oop, interface

I understand the concept of an interface in oop but implementing it is challenging for me.  These are my classes:

```
Public Class Alpha 
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property StartDate as Date
   Public Property System as string
   Public Sub Deserialize(ByVal row As DataRow)
       Me.Id = row("Id ") ...
   end sub
end class

Public Class Bravo
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property StartDate as Date
   Public Property Dosage as integer
   Public Sub Deserialize(ByVal row As DataRow)
       Me.Id = row("Id ") ...
   end sub
end class

Public Class Parent
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property Name as String
   Public Property AdmitDate as Date  
   Public Sub Deserialize(ByVal row As DataRow)
       Me.Id = row("Id ") ...
   end sub     
end class

Public Class AlphaList inherits List(of Alpha)
    Public Sub Deserialize(table As DataTable)
     For Each objRow As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim obj As New Bravo            
        obj.Deserialize(objRow)            
        Me.Add(obj)
     Next
    end sub    
end Class

Public Class BravoList inherits List(of Bravo)
    Public Sub Deserialize(table As DataTable)
     For Each objRow As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim obj As New Bravo            
        obj.Deserialize(objRow)            
        Me.Add(obj)
     Next
    end sub
end Class

Public Class ParentList inherits List(of Parent)
    Public Sub Deserialize(table As DataTable)
     For Each objRow As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim obj As New Parent
        obj.Deserialize(objRow)            
        Me.Add(obj)
     Next
    end sub
end Class
```

Currently, I have the following two functions in Class Parent

```
public Sub RunA(aList as AlphaList )
    For each item as Alpha in alist
       item.Id ....
    next
end sub
public Sub RunB(bList as BravoList )
    For each item as Bravo in bList 
       item.Id ....
    next
end sub
```

Basically, they have the same implementation, the only thing different is the argument - either a AlphaList or BravoList.

I want to create a function in Class Parent that takes any AlhpaList or BravoList.  How would I do this?  Thanks in advance!!  .. I would like to extract it out all together and do some thing like (pseudocode) :

```
public sub Run ( anyList List of Alpha or Bravo, any list of List of Parent)
```

Comment: Create a function that takes `Alpha` and `Bravo`, they would be different arguments...

Comment: but I can only take one Alpha or Bravo, not both...

Comment: Why only one? You can pass them both... `Public Sub Run (ByVal alphaList As Alpha, ByVal bravoList As Bravo)`... Then pass what you would need to. Either pass two objects as need or one or the other.

Comment: I could but I don't want to pass both .. I only want to pass one since the implementation is the same.  I don't want to have to maintain duplicate code in the same function.

Comment: Alpha & Bravo are different classes with different properties... I would recommend passing them both...Other wise just declare your argument as an object... Then you would have to do some checks...

Comment: I am only checking one property on both..-- the Start Date...i don't care about the other properties.  so you are saying, there is no way to have Alpha or Bravo implement from an interface? so that I can pass the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is not really possible. `Alpha` and `Bravo` are different types and so their `StartDate` properties are different properties. the fact that they have the same name doesn't change that.  You could use late-binding but that would be a filthy hack.

Even if you define an interface with a `StartDate` property and have `Alpha` and `Bravo` implement that, it still wouldn't allow you to pass a `List(Of Alpha)` or a `List(Of Bravo)` to a parameter that expects a `List(Of ISomeInterface)`.

If you were to have such an interface though, you could at least write a method that had a parameter of that type and then call it within your loops in the methods with the `List(Of Alpha)` and `List(Of Bravo)` parameters.

Comment: Okay, so I made my AlphaList  and BetaList implement an interface and I am passing that interface into the function.  What do you mean by "write a method that hada  parameter of that type...."

Comment: You'd have to have one interface for `Alpha` and `Bravo` to implement, so that `StartDate` would be the same member, and a second interface for `AlphaList` and `BravoList` to implement, so that you could have a method with a parameter of that type.

Comment: Thanks!  Got it.. I think I can vizualize it... i'll see if i can implement it.